# IF EXIST GOTO NEXT

Tags: batch-file

How do I get this script to go to INSTALLAX when the Framework is already installed?
It installs the Framework even if it already exists.

What am I missing?

```
Echo off
IF EXIST "%Programfiles(x86)%" (GOTO 64-Bit) ELSE (GOTO 32-Bit)

:32-Bit
IF EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe" GOTO INSTALLAX ELSE GOTO INSTALLFRAMEWORK

:64-Bit
IF EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe" GOTO INSTALLAX ELSE GOTO INSTALLFRAMEWORK

:INSTALLFRAMEWORK
start "" /w "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Prerequisites\Net Framework 4.0\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" /q /norestart
ECHO .NETFramework4.0Installed %Date% %TIME% >> \\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log\Framework\%COMPUTERNAME%.log

:INSTALLAX
start "" /w "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\DynamicsAX\setup.exe" RunMode=Custom HideUI=1 AcceptLicenseTerms=1 ByPasswarnings=0 InstallClientUI=1 ClientAOSServer=ax-aos02-prod AOSPort=2712 AOSWsdlPort=8101 ClientLanguage=en-us ConfigurePrerequisites=1 ClientConfigFile="\\sespfs01\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\AX_Icons\DAX_Prod(usr)32-bit.axc" LogDir="\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log"
ECHO AXDynamics2012Installed %Date% %TIME% >> \\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log\AXDynamics\%COMPUTERNAME%.log" GOTO END

:END
Exit
```

Comment: You're missing an ELSE in your IF clause in the :64-bit label.

Comment: Yes and more things missed than an ELSE, like an "&".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is obvious:

```
IF EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe" GOTO INSTALLAX GOTO INSTALLFRAMEWORK
```

no **ELSE** in the conditional.

And in the subs ":**INSTALLFRAMEWORK**" and ":**INSTALLAX**" you are not telling to exit the procedure so ":**INSTALLAX**" is always processed.

Also in the ":**INSTALLAX**" procedure you are using two commands without using the concatenate operator "**&**" (**Echo blabla >> file goto blabla**)

Here is the code:

```
@Echo off

Set "FW32=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe"
Set "FW64=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe"

IF EXIST "%Programfiles(x86)%" (
    REM 64BIT
    IF EXIST "%FW64%" (GOTO :INSTALLAX) ELSE (GOTO :INSTALLFRAMEWORK)
) ELSE (
    REM 32BIT
    IF EXIST "%FW32%" (GOTO :INSTALLAX) ELSE (GOTO :INSTALLFRAMEWORK)
)

:INSTALLFRAMEWORK
start "" /Wait "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Prerequisites\Net Framework 4.0\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" /q /norestart
ECHO .NETFramework4.0Installed %Date% %TIME% >> "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log\Framework\%COMPUTERNAME%.log"
Pause&Exit

:INSTALLAX
start "" /Wait "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\DynamicsAX\setup.exe" RunMode=Custom HideUI=1 AcceptLicenseTerms=1 ByPasswarnings=0 InstallClientUI=1 ClientAOSServer=ax-aos02-prod AOSPort=2712 AOSWsdlPort=8101 ClientLanguage=en-us ConfigurePrerequisites=1 ClientConfigFile="\\sespfs01\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\AX_Icons\DAX_Prod(usr)32-bit.axc" LogDir="\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log"
ECHO AXDynamics2012Installed %Date% %TIME% >> "\\server1\appdata01\Deployment\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Client_Log\AXDynamics\%COMPUTERNAME%.log"
Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You already did it right in the first IF statement (using parenthesis).

```
:32-Bit
IF EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe"
  (GOTO INSTALLAX) ELSE (GOTO INSTALLFRAMEWORK)

:64-Bit
IF EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\Extended\setup.exe"
  (GOTO INSTALLAX) ELSE (GOTO INSTALLFRAMEWORK)
```

(added newline for readability only)

Also, you were missing an ELSE.